# Proving for two integers $a, b, \text{ the } \gcd (a,b) \mid a,b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Found an exercise that states to prove that $(a,b) \mid a,b$. It wants to use the fact that for the set of linear combinations ($S = ax+by, x,y \in \mathbb {Z}$) of $a, b$, need be a smallest positive value, let $h$ (by the W.O. principle).  
Next, it wants to use the division algorithm to write $a = qh + r, 0 \le r \lt h$, to show that $r \in S$, and deduce that $h \mid a,b$.

I am not at all clear about the scheme, i.e. using the division algorithm,

Comment: I'm assuming, $(a,b)=\gcd(a,b)$, which divides $a,b$ by definition. Maybe refine your question?

Comment: Yes, I hoped it to be standard. Also, edited.

Comment: @junkquill The core issue was not to use the standard defn., but to use other way to prove. Also, this is a text's problem.

Comment: How do you define the g.c.d.?

Comment: @Bernard  It is the largest common divisor & the smallest linear combination. But, again the text wants that way.

Comment: 'Twas just to know on which basis you can work. I've posted a hint. See if it's enough.

Comment: Not to give the answer away, but to complement @Bernard's hint. Write $r = a(1) + b(-q)$.

Comment: @junkquill  It means need take a particular value of $h=b$, similarly can take another value of $h=a$, then $q=1, r=0$. But, this is still not an algebraic approach that I expected, say : $a = q(ax'+by') +r$, s.t. $x',y'$ yield the smallest linear combination. Hence, I stated that number theory is not capable of handling such analysis.

Comment: My apologies, I made a slight typo in my previous comment. I meant, take $r = a(1) + h(-q)$, but since we know $h \in S$, hence $h = ax + by$, for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitute that back in the equation of $r$, and you'll see that $r < h$ is a positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$, which is not possible. Hence $r=0$.

Comment: You mean $ r = a(1) + h(-q)$ be substituted back in $a = (ax'+by')(q) + r , \exists x'y' \in \mathbb{Z}$, s.t.$ h $ is the smallest positive linear combination. But, it sounds like only arriving at $0=0$ for a particular integer value pair $x',y'$.

Comment: Else, if I continue then, $r = a - ax'q - by'q \implies r = a(1-x'q) - by'q$. Hence, you mean that this proves by 'contra-positive', as the r.h.s. is a linear combination, and $h$ should be the smallest of $a,b$. But, to prove that $r$ is smaller than $h$, can only use again the definition of remainder, else how to prove $r \lt h$, i.e. $a(1-x'q) - by'q \lt ax' + by' \implies ax'(1 + q) + by'(1+q) -a \gt 0 \implies ax'(1 + q) + by'(1+q) -(ax'q + by'q +r ) \gt 0$ $ \implies (ax' + by' -r) \gt 0$. Is not there circularity of logic, as $r$ is again there. $h (= ax' + by') -r$ leads nowhere.

Comment: I apologise, I'm finding it a bit hard to follow your logic in these 2 comments. May be you can elaborate more? I've extended the comment I made as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have to prove the smallest positive element in $S$ divides $a$ and $b$.

Here's a hint: if $h$ does not divide $a$, for instance, prove that $r$ is a positive element of $S$.

*More details:*

Let $h$ be any positive element of $S$. If $h$ does not divide $a$,let's write the result of the Euclidean division of $a$ by $h$: $\; a=qh+r$ for some $q$, and $0<r<h$. We may rewrite this as 
$$r=a-qh \in S $$
since $h\in S$, and $r>0$. Thus we've found a positive element of $S$ smaller than $h$.

Similarly if $h$ does not divide $b$.

Comment: This is essentially the book's approach. I can pursue then by simple contradiction, and not by $a = hq +r$, where $h$ is a particular value of linear combination of $a,b$. I hope number theory cannot be used for that, so have to use the contradiction based approach..

Comment: I think @Bernard's hint should be more than enough to answer your question. And to use his hint, you *have* to use $a=hq+r$ i.e. the division algorithm

Comment: It's not really a proof by contradiction, but by contrapositive, which is much better.

Comment: @Bernard I could not really understand how it is contra-positive, and not by contradiction.

Comment: What you really prove is this: if an element $h\in S$ does not divide $a$ (or $b$) , it can't be the smallest positive element in $S$.  Many proofs are said ‘by contradiction’ by students, but are actually like this one.

Comment: Please elaborate your statement regarding : if an element $h \in S \nmid a,b \implies h$ is not the smallest element in $S$. I am unable to follow, you can check my comments to the OP, if they are in that direction.

Comment: @jitender: I've added some details. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: I hope that analytic NT would give AA based tools for analyzing statements like this better. Till then, I hope this is the way. Reason I am saying this is that assumption $h$ is the smallest linear combination is only told by WO principle, with no proof in 'depth' of $h \mid a,b$, & the only proof of that in elementary NT is in Gareth Jones' book Th.1.3(a), pg. #4. This is edifice, I feel on which linear combinations' NT based approach lies. If any other approach (linear algebra) is there for proving that there is one largest common divisor (lin. combn.) & it divides $a,b$, then please tell.

Comment: The implicit concept at work here is just that of `ideal` of a ring. The set $S$ of linear combinations of $a$ and $b$ is the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$, and, a $\mathbf Z$ is P.I.D., it happens that this ideal can be generated by a single element. This generator is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, that's what you're expected to prove.

Comment: I am here for some advice from you, I felt that AA concepts are a better way of explaining and hence useful in complex counting situations. Your response shows that the definition of an $ideal$ is the base from which to prove a specific property of ideals, and hence prove this. I feel that arriving from NT will not get help in ideals, but in somewhere else, say linear algebra, or something I do not know.

Comment: What do you denote AA?

Comment: Abstract algebra.

Comment: Ideals are concept from abstract algebra, which originated in number theory! What I tried to explain *is* abstract algebra.

Comment: So, in turn my question is : how will turning to ideals improve. I hope it will remain the same issue, as the base is number theory.

Comment: It will help to perceive the structure of what's happening. However, abstract algebra without a concrete backgrounds, like this one, is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over your question:

You need to prove $\gcd(a,b) \vert a,b$, by using the definition of $\gcd$ which says that it's the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Therefore, we have considered $S = \{ax+by\ \vert \ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. And we let $\gcd(a,b) = h \in S$. We have been given that $h$ is the smallest positive element of $S$. That is, there is no $t\in S$ such that $0<t<h$.

Now, let's consider $a$ and $h$. We can apply the division algorithm here i.e. $\exists\ q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=hq+r$, where either $r=0$ or $0<r<h$.

If we show that $0<r<h$ is not possible. We will get $r=0 \implies a=hq \implies h \vert a$. Which is what we want.

Now, we write $r = a-hq \ $, where $0<r<h$.

Since we know that $h \in S$, then we have $h = ax+by$, for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Giving us, $r = a-(ax+by)q=a(1-xq)+b(yq) \in S$. Hence we have $r\in S$, such that $0<r<h$, giving us a positive element of S smaller than $h$. But by our definition, $h$ was the smallest positive element of $S$.

Hence the case where $0<r<h$ is not possible. Giving us $r=0 \implies \gcd(a,b) \vert a$

Replicate the same argument for $b$.

Comment: Sorry, if had to use the argument of the assumption, then no need according to me to go that way. The book would have meant that, then seemingly not a proper exercise, at least as per me.

Comment: So, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I hope my last comment to @Bernard summarizes that. If not, then I will present a more polished edit.